# Is it possible to change the order of the Headers in a HttpWebResponseMessage using the ApiController?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, response-headers, asp.net-apicontroller

I have a legacy project which uses .NET Framework 4.5.2 and NancyModule.
When I get the result of a GET-request, then the Headers have the following order:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Content-Length | 206 |
| Content-Type | application/json; charset=utf-8 |
| Vary | Accept |
| Server | Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 |
| Link | </Servicename.xml>; rel="application/xml" |
| x-powered-by | ... |
| Date | Tue, 31 Jan 2023 13:25:07 GMT |

I transfer this project to .net 6 and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.
When I get the result of a GET-request, then the keys of the Headers are arranged alphabetically.

This leads me to the following question:
Is it possible to change the order of the headers?

I tried to remove and add several values of the dictionary in HttpContext.Response.Headers but it has no entries. When I added a custom header then it was also in alphabetical order.

Comment: Why would you need them to be in alphabetical order?

Comment: The last Header must be "Date". The reason ist that another legacy project expects that the last Header is "Date". Otherwise the project throws an exception.

Comment: So why aren't you doing the right thing and fixing that other legacy application which embeds a bad assumption about header ordering?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Sometimes you did not have the source and cannot reach the ear of the developers to rub their noses in that dirt ;o) - Sometimes it is even more worse and they tell it is your problem (some send me xml files which did not pass any xml file test)

Comment: I agree with you @Damien_The_Unbeliever, fixing the other legacy application would be the right thing but there are some issues that prevent me from doing it, so unfortunately this is not an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Kestrel (the default web server in ASP.NET Core) you might want to remove the `Server` header in order to **try** to have the `Date` header last.

But that would be very fragile, you can't really control the order of the headers, see the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/888c71f7f2269b6e67a24924cef66228857236f3/src/Servers/Kestrel/Core/src/Internal/Http/HttpHeaders.Generated.cs#L14804-L15190) of how it's done!

For simple HTTP responses that don't set any special headers, this might work and you might end up with something like that. Note the many conditionals used in the previous sentences.

```http
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 4536
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Tue, 31 Jan 2023 14:58:31 GMT
```

And here's how to disable the `Server` header for Kestrel:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions => serverOptions.AddServerHeader = false);
```

If you need to use HTTP.sys instead of Kestrel then you'll be out of luck since the `Content-Length` header is added after the `Date` header and there's [nothing you can do about it](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Servers/HttpSys/src/RequestProcessing/Response.cs#L327-L338).

```http
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Tue, 31 Jan 2023 15:11:23 GMT
Content-Length: 4536
```